# Error compiling for iOS 11 using Delphi Tokyo 10.2.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, delphi

I downloaded the trial version of `Delphi Tokyo 10.2.1` and I am trying to compile an app on mac with `xCode 9` and `iOS 11`. When it opens in the Mac `Simulator`, it appears the home screen and simply terminates the APP. The application is simple, it only has a button, it must be something necessary for `iOS 11` that Delphi does not have.

I read about this Patch, but my account is trial and I can not download it.

https://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30805

Comment: You can't install updates in the trial version. The issue has already been fixed by Embarcadero, but you have to be a paying customer to get the fix. Or wait for the next release that should include the fix.

Comment: OK! thanks for your answer!